# Accessing to pom.xml in jar

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jar, inputstream

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = args[0];
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(new File(filePath));
    Enumeration<JarEntry> zipEntries = jar.entries();
    String pomPath = null;
    for (JarEntry entry : Collections.list(zipEntries)) {
        if (entry.getName().contains("pom.xml")) {
            pomPath = entry.getName();
            System.out.println(pomPath);
        }
    }
```

}

now it prints out where the pom.xml located in jar file.
META-INF/maven/~~~~/~~~~/pom.xml

And now I want to access to pom.xml file.
I did some research and I think I need to use one of below

```
InputStream is = obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pomPath);
```

when calling this, I don't know what to use for the calling obj, so I just set up null string as a calling object and it says null pointer exception.

Also, I saw somewhere that I need to use `JarInputStream` to access `JarFile`.
But I have no idea using it. Help me!

Comment: instead of using obj.getClass(), you can use the class name directly. Say Foo is one of your classes in the jar. Foo.class.getClassLo..... I guess the pomPath should start with a /

Comment: Please tell us, *why* do you want to access `pom.xml`? This seems like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are in the class of the main, MainClass:

```
MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/....");
```

Mind that the path must start with a slash (absolute path), otherwise it would be relative to the package directory of that class.